# Google Sheets Using RegEX To Reformat & Concatenate

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Picture of the data][Link To Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RSVw5ocH4IQ01Xey2TZM_DNReXiD23SafTvoTYkyKN8/edit#gid=107394634)

- Sheet!1Name - Names are in Single Column
- Sheet!2Names - Names are in First Name, Last Name columns.

What I'm trying to do is basically remove any suffixes, special characters, and spaces, capitalize that information, and combine it with information from another field.

I was able to figure out how to piece together some regex that seems to effectively get rid of suffixes and removes special characters. It's below. That's where my skill set stops.

```
={"PlayerKey";ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(IF(ISBLANK(C2:C8),,PROPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C8," Jr\.$| J$| Sr\.$| S$|IV$|III$|II$|\.|-|'",""))))))}
```

I'm having trouble nesting formulas - i believe what i need to do is nest both concat and substitute but not sure if that's the method to get the "Desired Output example" that is in the sheet. I'm also having trouble understanding what order to do things, which is why i'm having trouble with 2Name i think.

Comment: Please edit your question and make it self-contained by also adding in it your test data

Comment: added in the screen shot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this in A1 of the new tab called MK.Help?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Player Key";UPPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(IF(MID(C2:C8,2,1)=".",INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C8," "),,1),LEFT(C2:C8))&D2:D8," Jr\.$| J$| Sr\.$| S$|IV$|III$|II$|\.|-|'",""))&E2:E8)})
```

Comment: that's awesome - so just two things - could you explain what parts are doing what? i've tried to get that working on a 1Name and i'm not doing something correctly. Also - let's say i wanted to add in a - between the players name and the position ... is that possible to? Just wanting to understand this as best as possible.

Comment: actually - i noticed one other little thing - so in the case of A.J. Epenesa it's making his key AJEPENESADL and not AEPENESA

Comment: to fix that AJ issue.... this is the slightly modified version of your formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Player Key";UPPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(IF(MID(C2:C8,2,1)=".",INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C8,"."),,1),LEFT(C2:C8))&D2:D8," Jr\.$| J$| Sr\.$| S$|IV$|III$|II$|\.|-|'",""))&E2:E8)})`

Comment: I had thought AJEPENESAD was the goal.  Apologies.  It's much simpler without that requirement of finding 'initial' names like "AJ". It should look like this instead:  =ARRAYFORMULA({"Player Key";UPPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(LEFT(C2:C8)&D2:D8," Jr\.$| J$| Sr\.$| S$|IV$|III$|II$|\.|-|'",""))&"-"&E2:E8)})

Comment: awesome... that's it!